# Calculating softmax cost function with loss adjustment, explain this code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, softmax

```
def loss(self, predictions, labels, param, training=True):
    hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, param.output_size)
    softmaxed = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels= hot_labels, logits=predictions)

    low_adj = np.logical_xor(labels==0,tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(predictions),1).numpy() == 0) * 0.4
    high_adj = np.logical_xor(labels==1,tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(predictions),1).numpy() == 1) * 0.2

    lossed = tf.reduce_mean(softmaxed + softmaxed*high_adj + softmaxed*low_adj)
    return lossed
```

I am working on a binary classification problem. The above is the loss function used for the same. However, this is someone else code, I don't quite understand why is *low_adj* and *high_adj* used?

What kind of adjustment is being made here? and if you explain why *0.4* and *0.2* is used? 
I am not able to see the bigger picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get this code? If I'm not mistaken, both logical conditions are actually the same... namely, true if and only if predictions and labels differ. So that part makes little sense, which then calls into question whether the rest makes any sense either...

Comment: From what I could read online regarding this so far, multiplying the loss with a constant emulates reweighting training samples. What do you have to say regarding this?  @xdurch0

Comment: @xdurch0 Also, I got this code from an archive of my organization.